# How to open UDP port with iptables in linux

Tags: linux, tcp, udp

Im playing around with my raspberry pi and i have a music box running (with mopidy). on addition to this i want to realize some other fancy stuff. i want to send a (UDP?)-Message from my Smartphone (With Tasker) to my PI. But i get always a "Connection Refused"-Message. I tried to open any UDP/TCP Port in iptables. 
To receive the messages i tried 
`netcat -ul 222`

for editing iptables im using:
`sudo nano /etc/network/iptables`
`sudo iptables-restore /etc/network/iptables`
`sudo iptables-save`
to see what ports are open im using:
`netstat -tuplen`
but i dont know what i have to expect on this output to realize my thing. am i on the right way or am i completely wrong :-) ?
finally i want to receive any messages to translate it to any other action (for exampe `reboot`)
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

```
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport <some port> -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --sport <some port> -j ACCEPT
```

To be frank though, without listing your current iptables config, there's no way to tell what's going on though you can have some 'dmesg' debug lines to help you out there:

```
-A LOGDROP -j LOG --log-prefix "packet dropped: " --log-level 7
-A LOGDROP -j DROP
```

where LOGDROP is what you jump to at the end of your input/output chains.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the complete command

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1700 -j ACCEPT
```